# (ByVal Target As Range) not working with a formula

Tags: excel

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value =     Range("A1").Value
End If
End Sub
```

Cell A1 has the formula " =C1" for example, yet when the value of the cell is changing, it isnt being added to the list of past values in the B column, yet new values will be added when A1 is changed manually.

Theres mountains of example code on here and google addressing this but after 2 hours of trying to trial and error my way through solutions, I feel like I have no choice but to ask for help.

I'm usually ok at finding the parts of a code I need to copy but all of the examples around the net are way to elaborate for me.

I'm trying my best to learn but would like help with this please.

Answer (score 0):

If A1 is referencing C1 then test if C1 has changed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A1").Value
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So you need to react if one of the dependents of the target you have changed is `A1`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 On Error GoTo mEnd
 If Not Intersect(Target.Dependents, Me.Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
  Me.Range("B" & Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.Range("A1").Value
 End If
mEnd:
 Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```